# Checking line number of permutation occurrence on permutations python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, permutation, python-itertools

I need a more optimal way of searching for line count for permutations with repeating. It works fine with smaller values, but in this case, it needs to go through  26 ^ 12 lines to check correct permutation. Any help?

```
from itertools import product
count = 0 
for i in product(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), repeat=12):
    count += 1
    if ''.join(i) == "INTELLIGENCE":
        print(count)
```

Comment: I don't understand - are you trying to count the number of instances? are you trying to count the number of newlines? are you searching for a specific expression?

Comment: If your lists of Cartesian products is sorted, you could do a binary search instead of a linear one. However, this most likely requires storing the entire list of products in memory. So you encounter the space-time tradeoff: you can increase the speed by using more memory space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some simple math:

```
>>> sum(26**i * (ord(c) - ord('A')) for i, c in enumerate('INTELLIGENCE'[::-1])) + 1
31302015863412429
```

Tried it with `'KUBET'` as well, result was `4922080`, same as with your code.

Alternatively:

```
count = 0
for c in 'KUBET':
    count = 26 * count + ord(c) - ord('A')
count += 1
```

Another:

```
>>> table = str.maketrans('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')
>>> int('INTELLIGENCE'.translate(table), 26) + 1
31302015863412429
```

Slight variation:

```
>>> int(''.join(chr(ord(c) - (10, 17)[c < 'J']) for c in 'INTELLIGENCE'), 26) + 1
31302015863412429
```

Yet another:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda count, c: 26 * count + ord(c) - ord('A'), 'INTELLIGENCE', 0) + 1
31302015863412429
```

Comment: Thanks the one with maketrans did the job!

Comment: @kubet Did the others not? They should all be equivalent.